# Rebase or Merge Git branch but Keep Deleted Files

Tags: git, github

I created my_branch from master (see the diagram below) for a subproject. I had to delete a lot of files from my_branch because they were irrelevant for the subproject but these files are still needed in master. For a while, the development was happening in both master and my_branch.

Now that the subproject is complete, I want to rebase or merge the changes from my_branch to master. But I want to keep all the files that were deleted in my_branch but still exist in master. What is the easiest way to do so?

I realize that I should probably have created a separate repository and refactor the projects. But given the situation at hand, what can I do, preferably not manually?

I cannot assume that all deleted files are in separate commits, unfortunately.

```
* 172c3f3 (origin/my_branch, my_branch) comment
| *   e4f6849 (origin/master, origin/HEAD, master) Merge branch asdf
| |\  
| | * c796e73 aafg
| |/  
| *   75720e5 Merge branch zxcv
| |\  
| | * 7c694e9 changes
| |/  
* | 61370ac some
* | 8afc0be development,
* | d14263b bugfixes,
* | 0d5a17f testing,
* | 588cf8f maybe some cleanup
* | 588cf8f here and there
* | e1f990b and a lot of files
* | 146212b removed
* | 09c6278 but they are still needed in master
|/  
*   9a53a83 my_branch created here
```

Comment: Thinking off the top of my head here - untrack all the files in master that you deleted in my_branch, then commit master.  Merge (or rebase) your my_branch into master.  Then track all files again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE** - My previous explanation of how to handle the `edit` commits during a rebase was unclear enough to be inaccurate. Clarifying

---

One workable approach (as suggested by Ben) is to edit the merge.  There is a potential down-side, in that this merge will violate assumptions made by some commands (e.g. `rebase` even when `--preserve-merges` is given).  This can cause such commands to silently produce corrupt results while reporting success.

There is an alternative, though it is more complicated.  It also involves rewriting the branch's history, but you mentioned that you might rebase the branch so I assume that's not a problem.

The idea here would be to discard the file deletions from the history, so that the files exist throughout, in the state they were in when the branch was created.  (Which honestly is probably what should've been done in the first place.)

The best procedure for this depends on a lot of things. Some are more generally workable (but more involved) while others are much simpler to execute (but only work if certain things are true).

It sounds like the files weren't all deleted at once, and were deleted in the same commits where other changes took place.

It's possible that an interactive rebase would work.  Certainly you could do it with `filter-branch`.  Some combination of the two might also be an option.

If `my_branch` is as linear as you depict - no merge commits on the branch - then you could probably get by with an interactive rebase.

```
git rebase --interactive master my_branch
```

In the TODO list that pops up, mark any commit that could contain unwanted deletions for `edit` (instead of the default `pick`).  As the rebase progresses, it will pause after tentatively committing each patch.  To find unwanted deletes you could do something like

```
git diff --diff-filter D --no-renames --name-only HEAD^
```

(Simpler commands will work; this tries to get just the list of deleted filenames so you can check which ones you want to reverse.  In particular, you may or may not want `--no-renames`; it's meant to avoid accidental triggering of rename detection that might prevent a delete from showing up, but if you really did rename a lot of files this will cause htem to show up as deletes.)

To reverse a particular delete

```
git checkout HEAD^ -- path/and/filename
```

When you have the deletes reversed

```
git add .
git commit --amend
```

The above rebase command will also complete the rebasing of your work onto the tip of `master`.  If you *don't* want that - e.g. if you want to merge the work into `master` instead - you could do something like

```
git rebase --interactive `git merge-base my_branch master` my_branch
```

If that seems too manual, or if there are complexities that would keep it from working, then you might prefer a `filter-branch` - but be warned that if the history is large this could be slow.

In this case what you need is a `tree-filter` that re-adds the deleted files.  I would start by getting a local copy of all the files as of the merge base

```
git checkout `git merge-base master my_branch`
cp all/the/files/that/were/deleted some/path/where/I/can/find/them/later
```

Then

```
git filter-branch --tree-filter 'cp some/path/where/I/can/find/them/later all/the/files/that/were/deleted' -- my_branch
```

Comment: Thanks, Mark, this was educational. I was able to use your approach to do the merge (I did not need all of it thankfully). I did use parts of Ben's answer above too.

Comment: Is this also works for directory? edited: for those using zsh, use this instead: `git checkout HEAD~ -- your/directory` it is also works to check for previously deleted files in the current head, really thanks @Mark Adelsberger

Answer (score 2):

from your `master` branch, do a merge and pass the `--no-commit` flag:

`git merge my_branch --no-commit`

Now you can un-delete the files that the merge wants to delete:

`git reset HEAD <file>`

`git checkout -- <file>`

The command `git status` will show you which files it wants to delete, if you are so inclined, you can parse this output with a script to selectively reset/checkout all deleted files

And then proceed to commit the final result:

`git commit`

Comment: While this seems straightforward and should work, I don't necessarily recommend it.  The reason is that further rebases could wreak havoc if they encounter your merge.  If a merge would be successful (but generate unwanted results) using the default strategy, then it's somewhat dangerous to use `--no-commit` to edit the merge.  If you know you can never rebase through merges in this repo anyway - e.g. if you already have so-called "evil merges" - then it's fine. If not, I would consider a different approach (which I'll post as a separate answer)

Comment: Thanks Ben and Mark: I used elements of both your advice but Mark's was a bit more useful.